# Qt Combine double / string in function

Tags: string, qt4, int

How to combine `double` and `string` variable into one function?

I call function which receives `double` parameter as:

`counter(&filesize)`,

than call function:

```
void Properties::counter(double *filesize)
{
    double res = *filesize;
    QString filetyperes;

    if (res <= 1024) { res = res; filetyperes = "B"; }
    else if (res > 1024 && res <= 1024*1024) { res = res / 1024; filetyperes = "KiB"; }
    else if (res > 1024*1024 && res <= 1024*1024*1024) { res = res / 1024 / 1024; filetyperes = "MiB"; }
    else if (res > 1024*1024*1024) { res = res / 1024 / 1024 / 1024; filetyperes = "GiB"; }

    *filesize = res;
}
```

And it will receive double parameter and calculates properly.

But, I have conversion MiB/KiB so instead of

`*filesize = res + filetyperes` which returns example (`1 KiB`) for an example.

But my parameters return only double, so I can add `(const double *filesize)` but it throwns an error.

header.h is:

```
private:
      void counter(double *filesize = 0);
```

Thank you.

Comment: Are you interested in returning the double value for your filesize alone or do you want the full string including the filetyperes value?

Comment: Whatever, return as string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should return a QString with your filesize and filetyperes concatenated:

```
QString Properties::counter(double *filesize)
{
    double res = *filesize;
    QString filetyperes;

    if (res <= 1024) { res = res; filetyperes = "B"; }
    else if (res > 1024 && res <= 1024*1024) { res = res / 1024; filetyperes = "KiB"; }
    else if (res > 1024*1024 && res <= 1024*1024*1024) { res = res / 1024 / 1024; filetyperes = "MiB"; }
    else if (res > 1024*1024*1024) { res = res / 1024 / 1024 / 1024; filetyperes = "GiB"; }

    *filesize = res;
    return QString::number(res) + filetyperes;
}
```

Comment: When calling function as `QString::number(Properties::counter(filesize))` filesize receives double and it should return string (Qstring), but I'm still got an error as: No matching function for call `Properties::counter(double&)` ! Candidate is included `   double filesize = 0;` I have declared variable filesize as `double` before is calling an function.

Comment: Works, calling as `Properties::counter(&filesize)` solves a problem. Thank you.